# invalid destination language error occurs

Tags: python, googletrans

```
def translate_language(lan):
    x = 0
    out = str(lan)
    while x < 1000:
        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en")
        translator = googletrans.Translator()
        translation = translator.translate(text, dest=out)
        print(translation.text)
        converted_audio = gtts.gTTS(translation.text, lang=out)
        SpeakText(translation.text)
        x = x + 1
```

I am passing language code to this function and store it in out variable by converting it into a string. When I use out variable for language it works fine but when I use it in dest, it raises error : invalid destination language. What should I do??

I have tried making it string value or removing it. T=when I use the same variable as language value it works fine but doesnot work with dest